# Как запретить Linux монтировать разделы для Windows

Tags: linux, windows, uefi, монтирование

Я хочу запретить Linux доступ к системному диску Windows и разделу UEFI (сам Linux установился как бы *'под BIOS'*, хотя реальная система *UEFI*). Казалось бы, достаточно просто не монтировать раздел, но в том дело, что я хочу это запретить вообще. Монтировать в *RO* не хочу, т к не хочу сломать систему *(кто монтировал NTFS после работы с Windows, тот наверняка вспомнит ошибку `The filesystem wasn't safely closed on Windows`)*. Пробовал через скрипт в systemd:

`#!/bin/bash`

`while true; do`

`if [[ $(mount | grep /dev/sdb)="" ]]; then`

`:`

`else`

`umount /dev/sdb1`

`umount /dev/sdb2`

`umount /dev/sdb3`

`umount /dev/sdb4`

`fi`

`done`

Однако, по /dev мне нельзя детектировать разделы, ибо у меня (почему-то) иногда меняются эти метки. Диск с Linux может быть то /dev/sda2, то /dev/sdb2. Так как запретить Linux доступ к дискам с Windows и UEFI?

Comment: В первую очередь вместо sdaN и sdbN использовать [постоянные имена разделов](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Persistent_block_device_naming_(Русский))

Comment: Беда в том, что мне надо как-то чекать mount-ы, а там все записано как /dev/sdXn. Да и, если так подумать, этот скрипт скорее бесполезен, в случае чего достаточно просто примонтировать диск и все. Так что тут надо прямо запрещать монтирование вообще. А вот это сделать никак (точнее, можно попробовать через SELinux, но для меня это лютый хардкор, найти бы способ попроще)

Comment: вроде бы их (разделы ntfs) надо добавить в fstab, но с опцией **noauto**

Comment: мысль интересная, особенно для NTFS разделов. Хотя, и UEFI мне нельзя монтировать - и вовсе не из-за пресловутого NTFS. Я же говорил, что хотя реальная система у меня UEFI, Linux установился "под BIOS". noauto же не даст разделу монтироваться, если на него зайти в GUI файловом менеджере (Thunar)?

Comment: А можно узнать нафига тебе это надо?

Comment: don Rumata, у меня две ОС стоят, причём Linux стоит 'под BIOS', а вот Windows стоит нормально, 'под UEFI'. Мне надо запретить монтирование диска с Windows и раздела с UEFI. Причина, думаю, понятна, про ошибку *The filesystem wasn't safely closed on Windows* я говорил.

Comment: Попробуй `nobootwait` добавить в fstab.

Comment: don Rumata, так ```nobootwait``` продолжает загрузку системы даже в случае ошибок при монтировании, но мне нужно **вообще избежать монтирования дисков с Windows и UEFI**